# url rewrite using htacces in my case

Tags: .htaccess, url

i am rewriting my url using htaccess my orginal url is

```
http://www.example.com/products/product_detail.php?url=pro-name
```

my desired url will come like this

```
http://www.example.com/products/pro-name
```

but i am partially done with this url

```
 http://www.example.com/products/product_detai/pro-name
```

using this .htaccess code

```
RewriteRule product_detail/url/(.*)/ product_detail.php?url=$1
RewriteRule /(.*) product_detail.php?url=$1
```

here i did not know how to get my desired url . please help anyone to get the desire url. thanks

Answer (score 1):

Enable mod_rewrite and .htaccess through `httpd.conf` and then put this code in your `.htaccess` under `DOCUMENT_ROOT` directory:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks -MultiViews
# Turn mod_rewrite on
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,}\s/+(products)/product_detail.php\?url=([^\s]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/%2? [R=302,L]

RewriteRule ^(products)/(.+?)/?$ /$1/product_detail.php?url=$2 [L,NC,QSA]
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#Assuming the correct RewriteBase is used...

#Redirect the client to the fancy url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^product_detail\.php$ %1? [R,L]

#Rewrite the url internally and stop rewriting
#to prevent a loop
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ product_detail.php?url=$1 [END]
```

In this code you first redirect the client to the url that you want to be visible in the address bar. `%1` matches the first capture group of the RewriteCond. The trailing `?` clears the query string. The second rule rewrites the url internally so that the server can actually generate output instead of a 404 error. The END-flag (available from apache 2.3.9 and up; [docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_end)), will stop rewriting url's completely). This is to prevent an never-ending loop where the url get's constantly rewritten. ([docs](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html))

Edit: Versions of apache below 2.3.9 don't have the END-flag. To prevent a loop you'll need to work around that. You can use for example:

```
#Assuming the correct RewriteBase is used...

#Redirect the client to the fancy url
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} !redirect=true
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^url=(.*)$
RewriteRule ^product_detail\.php$ %1? [R,L]

#Rewrite the url internally and stop rewriting
#to prevent a loop
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ product_detail.php?url=$1&redirect=true [L]
```

Comment: thanks for your support. but this code is given 500 page error

Comment: I just tested it and there is no syntax error in my code. You are most likely using a version of apache that is less than 2.3.9, which doesn't future the `END` flag. You'll need to work around it or need to upgrade your version of apache.